# Android Marketplace: Are the details (name etc) in the keystore user-visible?

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, keytool, signing

When I sign my app for release on the Android Marketplace I create a keystore file using the keytool application following the instructions here http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html. This tool asks for first and last name, organizational unit, and more.

Now my question is, will the eventual user of the app actually be able to see these details? Or is it all something internal to the Android Marketplace?  I'm particularly wondering about the first and last name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details that you see in the Marketplace on the web and on the devices are details that are provided inside your Google Android Marketplace account - not retrieved from the ketstore you use to sign your app.

Answer (score 2):

It's internal to the marketplace the user wont be able to see those details.Only when you are exporting your package with the keystore you can see those details not anywhere else as i know.